# UILongPressGestureRecognizer breaks tableView scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uitapgesturerecognizer

I created a custom Label class that contains a UILongPressGestureRecognizer, and I am invoking it in tableview cells in a TableViewController. The long press gesture recognizer works (two clickable zones in an attributed sting), but the tableView containing the labels no longer scrolls (pans) if the scroll gesture begins in one of the UILongPressGestureRecognizer zones of my CustomLabel. I have tried `cancelsTouchesInView = false` as well as the various responses below, to no avail. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I've spent a week on this problem. My code is below.

Here is the CustomLabel class:

```
class CustomLabel: UILabel {

    let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
    let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: CGSize.zero)
    var textStorage = NSTextStorage() {
        didSet {
            textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)
        }
    }

    var onCharacterTapped: ((_ label: UILabel, _ characterIndex: Int, _ state: Bool) -> Void)?

    let tapGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer()

    override var attributedText: NSAttributedString? {
        didSet {
            if let attributedText = attributedText {

                if attributedText.string != textStorage.string {

                textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: attributedText)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    let characterDelay = TimeInterval(0.01 + Float(arc4random()) /  Float(UInt32.max)) / 100

                    for (index, char) in attributedText.string.characters.enumerated() {

                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + characterDelay * Double(index)) {
                            print("character ch is: \(char) at index: \(index)")
                            super.attributedText = attributedText.attributedSubstring(from: NSRange(location: 0, length: index+1))
                        }
                    }
                }
                }

            } else {
                textStorage = NSTextStorage()
            }
        }
    }

    override var lineBreakMode: NSLineBreakMode {
        didSet {
            textContainer.lineBreakMode = lineBreakMode
        }
    }

    override var numberOfLines: Int {
        didSet {
            textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = numberOfLines
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setUp()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setUp()
    }

    func setUp() {
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
        textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
        textContainer.lineBreakMode = lineBreakMode
        textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = numberOfLines
        tapGesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CustomLabel.labelTapped(_:)))
        tapGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0
        tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        //tapGesture.delegate = self.superview
        addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        textContainer.size = bounds.size
    }

    func labelTapped(_ gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

        let locationOfTouch = gesture.location(in: gesture.view)
        let textBoundingBox = layoutManager.usedRect(for: textContainer)
        let textContainerOffset = CGPoint(x: (bounds.width - textBoundingBox.width) / 2 - textBoundingBox.minX, y: (bounds.height - textBoundingBox.height) / 2 - textBoundingBox.minY)
        let locationOfTouchInTextContainer = CGPoint(x: locationOfTouch.x - textContainerOffset.x, y: locationOfTouch.y - textContainerOffset.y)
        let indexOfCharacter = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: locationOfTouchInTextContainer, in: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)

        if gesture.state == .began {

            onCharacterTapped?(self, indexOfCharacter, true)

        } else if gesture.state == .ended {

            onCharacterTapped?(self, indexOfCharacter, false)

        }

    }

}
```

Here is the cellClass:

```
class friendTextCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var labelText: CustomLabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

}
```

And here is selections from the TableViewControllerClass where CustomCells are created:

```
class UsersViewController: UITableViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

private func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {return true}


    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRequireFailureOf otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return gestureRecognizer === longPressRecognizer &&
            (otherGestureRecognizer.view?.isDescendant(of:tableView) ?? false)
    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "friendText", for: indexPath) as! friendTextCell

        print("keyArrrrray is: \(keyArray)")

        if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row < keyArray.count {
            self.removeInstructions()
            cell.labelText.font = cell.labelText.font.withSize(17)
            let text = "> "+namesArray[indexPath.row] + ": " + linkArray[indexPath.row]
            let name = namesArray[indexPath.row]
            let link = linkArray[indexPath.row]
            let imageLink = imageURLArray[indexPath.row]
            let nameChCount = name.characters.count
            let linkChCount = link.characters.count

            let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: name + ": " + link, attributes: nil)

            let totalChCount = attributedString.string.characters.count

            let linkRange = NSMakeRange(0, nameChCount) // for the word "link" in the string above

            let linkAttributes: [String : AnyObject] = [
                NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white, NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue as AnyObject]
            attributedString.setAttributes(linkAttributes, range:linkRange)

            cell.labelText.attributedText = attributedString

            cell.labelText.onCharacterTapped = { label, characterIndex, state in

                let highlight: [String : AnyObject] = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.black, NSBackgroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white]

                if state == true {
                    if characterIndex < nameChCount {
                        print("name press began at character \(characterIndex)")
                        attributedString.addAttributes(highlight, range:NSMakeRange(0, nameChCount))
                        cell.labelText.attributedText = attributedString
                    } else if characterIndex > nameChCount {
                        print("link press began at character \(characterIndex)")
                        let startPos = nameChCount + 2
                        let endPos = totalChCount-nameChCount-2
                        attributedString.addAttributes(highlight, range:NSMakeRange(startPos, endPos))
                        cell.labelText.attributedText = attributedString
                    }

                } else if state == false {

                    if characterIndex < name.characters.count {

                        if let userVC:UserViewTableViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "UserVC") as? UserViewTableViewController {
                            userVC.userName = name
                            userVC.shareLink = link
                            userVC.imageLink = imageLink
                            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(userVC, animated: true)
                        }

                }

                if characterIndex > name.characters.count && characterIndex <= link.characters.count + name.characters.count {

                    //extract link from array
                    let link = self.linkArray[indexPath.row]
                    print("on click link is: \(link)")

                    //Present SafariViewController with link
                    let svc = SFSafariViewController(url: NSURL(string: link)! as URL)
                    self.present(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)

                }
                }

            }

        } else if keyArray.isEmpty && indexPath.section == 0 {

            cell.labelText.text = "..."

        }

        if indexPath.section == 1 && keyArray.count <= 1 {
            let message = "> Press the + button to add more friends."
            cell.labelText.animate(newText: message, characterDelay: TimeInterval(0.01 + Float(arc4random()) /  Float(UInt32.max)) / 200)
        } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
            cell.labelText.text = ""
        }

        return cell

    }
```

Comment: try implementing the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` method called     `optional public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool` returning true

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried this as well in both the CustomCell class and the tableViewController class. Didn't work. Where would you place this method?

Comment: I will post some example

Comment: @ReinierMelian, I added more of my code to the question above, give that my issue seems to stem from no being able to communicate between the tableViewController class and the CustomLabel class...?

Comment: Could it be a problem related to UIGestureRecognizer delegation?

Comment: @ReinierMelian Just curious what you were thinking in terms of examples. Very curious if you provide a bit of context about how to use the shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith method you mentioned.

Comment: I was working on this yesterday but I can't make it works as you need so, that is why I don't post anything here

Comment: @ReinierMelian Thanks for letting me know. Do you think it's because the GestureRecognizer and the tableView are in different Classes?

Comment: the problem is the `tableView.panGestureRecognizer.delegate` can't be assigned to the viewController

Comment: @ReinierMelian You mean can't be assigned to the TableViewController?

Comment: @ReinierMelian So do I need to move the LongPressGestureRecognizer creation from the CustomCell to the TableviewController?

Comment: I could be mistaken, but don't you need to call `textfield.resignFirstResponder` after you're done with your `LongPressGestureRecognizer`? That way you'll be able to interact with your tableView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> tableView containing the labels no longer scrolls (pans) if the scroll gesture begins in one of the UILongPressGestureRecognizer

This problem occurs when you set the UILongPressGestureRecognizer's minimum press duration to 0 and it starts to grab the scroll view's embedded gesture recognizer. You can resolve it by using bigger delay, if you need to use long press gesture recognizer with delay, how it's supposed to be.
First will respond your table view's `didSelectRow at` and after delay your selector.
It worked for me, although i removed `tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false` and added attribute `@objc` before declaring your selector method for recognizer (requires if you write in swift 4).

If you want to use `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` with no delay, just use `UITapGestureRecognizer`. In this case table view will scroll, but you can't receive `didSelectRow` method if you tap on the label.
Table and Collection views gestures delegates are set to underlying scroll view so you cant use `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` methods on your `UIViewController` for that purpose. 
If you want to receive some kind of callback in you View Controller when that recognizer fires, you can throw call back by implementing delegate methods.

Create `CustomLabel`'s delegate that implements `labelTapped` function for example. In your selector call that delegate function. Make your cell conform to that delegate and repeat that in your cell to throw function to your `UIViewController`. Also you can use closure delegate pattern.

Hope that helps.

**Update**

So the solution is to make `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` 's `minimumPressDuration` to 0 as you initially did and assign the delegate to it's cell (superview in my case). 
In cell you need to override this method:

```
gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return gestureRecognizer == yourGesture || otherGestureRecognizer == yourGesture
}
```

By the way you don't need to make your cell conform to `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` as it already does

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm using UILongPress because I want to change the background colour of the text when the press begins, and turn it off when the press ends. UITapGesture doesn't allow me this possibility as far as I could tell. Do tell me if I'm wrong. Also, I tried adding a slight delay of 0.1 but it causes the inverse problem where the tableview scroll grabs the gesture and the CustomLabel gesture recognizer doesn't respond.

Comment: I think you just have to use `didSelectRow` and `didDeselectRow` methods on your table view. Then you can pass the call to your cell to update label's background. If you want to change default selection style on cell. Use cell's `selectionStyle` property set to .none

Comment: Thanks. Your solution would work if my entire cell was the button, but I need two clickable zones within the cell, each with its own press and release detection.

Comment: @luciusdegeer Aha! So I found the solution. Delegates for TableView's gesture recognizer is in it's cells, so you just need to set it as a delegate for your gesture as well. I will update my post with the correct implementation.;)

Comment: Thanks so much for this response. I'm trying to figure out what exactly you mean by "assign the delegate to it's cell". I had tried setting the LongPress's delegate to the tableview like this: `cell.labelText.tapGesture.delegate = self`. Is this what you mean? I placed this in my cellForRowAtIndexPath method in the tableView

Comment: I also tried without success to add the following to func setup() in my CustomCell class: `tapGesture.delegate = self.superview as! UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` but it causes a crash. XCode requires that I force the superview to conform to UIGestureRecognizerDelegate in this way that causes a crash, so I tried adding UIGestureRecognizerDelegate to the list of conformances at the top of the class definition.

Comment: Perhaps you can specify how you would set the delegate with reference to my code? I believe I tried two ways of doing what you suggested, but neither worked. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding you, in which case a code example would help.

Comment: @luciusdegeer in your cell place labelText.tapGesture.delegate = self or in your label place tapGesture.delegate = self.superview if superview is your cell

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've tried tapGesture.delegate = self.superview but I get the following error "Cannot assign value of type 'UIView?' to type 'UIGestureRecognizerDelegate?''.

Comment: I also tried assigning the delegate within the cell class like so: 
`class friendTextCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var labelText: CustomLabel!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        labelText.tapGesture.delegate = self
    }
    
}`

Comment: The case in last comment should be correct, check that you’re r not reassigning delegate somewhere else and why do you need layoutIfNeeded

Comment: I agree, it should be correct, and I had tried these options. But they are not working. I'm not assigning the delegate elsewhere, I triple checked. Any idea why I cannot (as mentioned in my comment) assign the delegate to the superview from within my CustomLabel class?

Comment: Can you provide me with some code, or send me the project it would be easier den.litvinn@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
tapGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0
```

With

```
tapGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.5
```

The recognition is starting too soon and not getting the table to get touches

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this and it causes the opposite problem. The tableview scroll grabs the gesture but the CustomLabel gesture recognizer doesn't respond. I need the tableView and the CustomLabel's gesture recognizers to receive the same trigger (and ideally without introducing a delay).

Comment: So I guess @reinier-melian solution is best

Answer (score 1):

In this case you need to implement the [UIGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate) delegate.  I would use the method [gestureRecognizer(_:shouldRequireFailureOf:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate/1624229-gesturerecognizer) and return true.  This means your longPressGesture will not fire until all of the other gesture recognizers (specifically the tableView Pan) have failed.

```
class UIViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
  var longPressRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer!
  var tableView: UITableView!
  func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRequireFailureOf otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
      return gestureRecognizer === longPressRecognizer &&
             (otherGestureRecognizer.view?.isDescendant(of:tableView) ?? false)
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry thats the internal parameter name for parameter 2.  I fixed the example.

Comment: got back to my computer see update.  which compiles in my playground

Comment: I tried this in both the TableViewController and the CustomLabel class, and it doesn't resolve the issue. Is there an added dimension to my case given that the tableview and UILongPressGestureRecognizer are in separate class files? (TableViewController and CustomLabel)